# Finding magic strings in Intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to find all the strings value in my non test classes which are not assigned to final static  constants.

Intellij Idea has a code inspection to find magic numbers: is it possible to run a similar search on strings ?

Answer (score 2):

The *Hard coded strings* inspection may be what you want. It reports String literals and can be configured to ignore literals assigned to constants.